# Is "\citet{StudyA,StudyB}" better or worse than "\citet{StudyA} and \citet{StudyB}"?

Tags: citing, natbib

## Introduction

Suppose I wish to cite two studies with the keys `StudyA` (written by AuthorA in 2018) and `StudyB` (written by AuthorB in 2017). Importantly, AuthorA \ne AuthorB.

I could cite them by putting both keys in one `\citet` call, as follows:

> Recently, `\citet{StudyA,StudyB}` demonstrated neat things.

The above is rendered with a semicolon: "Recently, *AuthorsA* [2018]; *AuthorsB* [2017] demonstrated neat things." The semicolon seems odd to me as it breaks the flow.

I could manually separate the two, as in the following:

> Recently, `\citet{StudyA}` and `\citet{StudyB}` demonstrated neat things.

This produces the following line: "Recently, *AuthorsA* [2018] and *AuthorsB* [2017] demonstrated neat things." To my eyes, this looks better.

Presumably `\citet`, as well as any external classes and `*.sty` files (such as those provided to me by the journal I'm writing for), have been developed to produce the preferred behavior.

## Question

As a *general* rule of thumb, should I use `\citet{StudyA,StudyB}` over `\citet{StudyA} and \citet{StudyB}` in my `*\TeX` writings? What factors might influence this, provided my publisher's citation guidelines are silent on this topic?

Answer (score 5):

If you employ `\citet` -- "text-style citation call-out" -- with multiple arguments, you are abusing the command, *unless* all cited items have the exact same set of authors. (In such a case, the author name(s) won't be repeated.) Using `\citep` with multiple items is always OK, though.

See p. 9 of the user guide of the `natbib` package for more information.

You asked,

> should I use `\citet{StudyA,StudyB}` or `\citet{StudyA}` and `\citet{StudyB}`?

The latter. Definitely.

---

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{j3001a,author="Jones",title="{ABC}",year=3001}
@misc{j3001b,author="Jones",title="{DEF}",year=3001}
@misc{j3002,author="Jones", title="{GHI}",year=3002}
@misc{m4001a,author="Miller",title="{UVW}",year=4001}
@misc{m4001b,author="Miller",title="{XYZ}",year=4001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\citet{j3001a,j3001b,j3002} -- OK

\citet{j3002,m4001b} -- \emph{not OK}

\citet{j3002} and \citet{m4001b} --  OK

\medskip
\citep{j3001a,j3001b,j3002} -- OK

\citep{j3002,m4001a,m4001b} -- this is OK too

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not hold for `biblatex`. `\textcite` goes through great lengths to make sure that `\textcite{sigfridsson,worman,cicero,geer}` looks good although the list of authors is different.

Comment: @moewe - I didn't claim that it applied to `\textcite`, did I? I thought I was writing about `natbib`'s `\citet` macro...  Was I insufficiently clear? If so, I'll be happy to rephrase some of the answer.

Comment: Absolutely not. I added my comment just in case someone using `biblatex` stumbles over this and thinks your advice also applies to `biblatex`'s `\textcite` (or `\citet` in `natbib` compatibility mode).

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for this clarification. (I think it's worth pointing out, from time to time, that `\citet` under biblatex is *not* fully the same as `\citet` under `natbib`...)